# Como multiplicar todos los elementos de un array por un escalar con numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, numpy

Pongamos que tengo un array de precios en dolares. En este caso tengo 10 elementos que varían entre 1 y 1001.

```
dolares = np.random.choice(np.arange(1,1001),size = 10)
```

```
[300 400 64 210 496 265 485 943 595 327]
```

Quiero convertir todos los precios a otra moneda multiplicando por un escalar. En mi caso, multiplicar por 1.5, de manera que me salga algo así:

```
[450  600 ...]
```

¿Cual es la manera correcta de plantearlo?

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Lectura recomendada: [Te he votado negativamente porque hacer una investigación previa es necesario para realizar una buena pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2878#2878). Multiplica directamente: `dolares * 1.5`

Comment: Buenas, me he leído gran parte de la documentación de numpy buscando un método que realizara lo que busco y he investigado al respecto de si podía usar algún método como map() , preguntar aquí no es lo primero que se me ha ocurrido. No esperaba que fuera algo tan obvio. Gracias por el consejo igual

Comment: Yo creo que [esto (Broadcasting)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) podría ser de utilidad.

Comment: Google "tu pregunta" -> https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/numpy/multiply-array-with-scalar-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

Si dólares es un array de numpy, simplemente agregas el valor por el que quieres multiplicar, y numpy se encarga de reconocer que se trata de un producto escalar-vector y lo realiza elemento a elemento:

```
nueva_moneda = 1.5*dolares
```